# C++ Arena Allocator Free Memory is Always Half

Tags: c++, memory-management

```
const int size = 50000;
char pool[size];

int freeMemory(void)
{
int freemem = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if(pool[i] == NULL)
    {
        freemem++;
    }
    i++;
}

return freemem;
}
```

If I call freeMemory(), the size returned is always HALF of what originally declared. 25000 specifically here Even if I'm not initializing anything in the pool itself. Why is this? Do I need to initialize something first?

```
void initialize(void)
{
//Don't quite understand if I need to initialize something here? 
}
```

And I'm trying to avoid using the new operator too. The reason being is that I'm trying to manually manage the memory inside the pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have an extra `i++;` statement in your for loop. So each iteration actually increments the iterator twice, effectively making you only loop half the times.

Remove the `i++;` line at the end of your for loop.

Comment: Wow! How silly of me. I apologize for taking up your time for that lol

Comment: @user2229804 Hey no worries, happens to all of us. Upvote and mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem.

Comment: @user2229804 Ah no worries :) Was just making sure since your account is new, in case you weren't already familiar with the site.